# How do I return a value of another user from database in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am using the basic authentication system included in laravel package and have a user schema which contains the following:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

I am using `Auth::user()->name` to return the name of current user.

Is there a pre-defined function to return the name of user with a specific id?

If not, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Auth::user()->name` to return the name of the user then you can use `Auth::user()->id` to return that user's `id`.

Please add more details to the question you are asking?

`Auth::user()` is basically a `middleware` that checks if the user is logged in or not. It will only return the value of the logged user.

Now if you want to get the data of a user using an id. You can user controller function..

first of all declare `User` class on top of controller

```
use User;
```

Then write the function

```
public function getUser($id)
{
    $user = User::where('id','=',$id)
    ->first();
    return $user;
}
```

to access it

go to `web.php` and write a `route`

```
Route::get('/user/{id}','YourController@getUser');
```

and now access it through

```
localhost:8000/user/1
```

Answer (score 0):

User is a model located here:

```
App\User;
```

You can reference this model and use `Eloquent` to do it by finding a specific user by their ID:

```
$user = App\User::find($id);
```

Alternative, you can use the fluid query builder if you prefer:

```
$user = Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::table('users')->where('id', $id)->first();
```

Both of these methods will work correctly. It just depends on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I would sincerely recommend to go and [read the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent).

```
$user = App\User::find($id);
// Check if null or use App\User::findOrFail($id)
$user->name();
```